# SPSS Macro to open CSV from variable

Tags: debugging, macros, syntax-error, spss

I am new to SPSS macros and trying to open a CSV file from a specified path in a variable.

Note that I want to set all variable settings at the top of the file, so I can easily decide to import another file with a different name.

This is my code:

```
/* settings */
define !SYMB() "VIX". !enddefine.
define !CSVFILE() "E:\Downloads\$" + !SYMB + ".csv". !enddefine.

/* import csv file */
GET DATA
  /TYPE=TXT
  /FILE=!CSVFILE
  /DELCASE=LINE
  /DELIMITERS=","
  /ARRANGEMENT=DELIMITED
  /FIRSTCASE=1
  /IMPORTCASE=ALL
  /VARIABLES=
  V1 5X
  Date ADATE10
  !SYMB + 'O' F7.2
  !SYMB + 'H' F7.2
  !SYMB + 'L' F7.2
  !SYMB + 'C' F7.2.
CACHE.
EXECUTE.
DATASET NAME "DataSet" + !SYMB WINDOW=FRONT.
```

Unfortunately I am getting the following errors:

> /* settings */ define !SYMB() "VIX". !enddefine. define !CSVFILE()
>   "E:\Downloads\$" + !SYMB + ".csv". !enddefine.
>
> > Warning # 207 in column 13.  Text: E:\Downloads\$
> >     A '+' was found following a text string, indicating continuation, but the next
> >     non-blank character was not a quotation mark or an apostrophe.
>
> /* import csv file */ GET DATA   /TYPE=TXT   /FILE=!CSVFILE
>
> > Error.  Command name: GET DATA
> >     (2256) Invalid subcommand: FILE
> >     Execution of this command stops.
> >
> > Error # 1.  Command name: +
> >     The first word in the line is not recognized as an SPSS Statistics command.
> >     Execution of this command stops.   /DELCASE=LINE
> >
> > Error # 1.  Command name: /DELCASE
> >     The first word in the line is not recognized as an SPSS Statistics command.
> >     Execution of this command stops.   /DELIMITERS=","   /ARRANGEMENT=DELIMITED   /FIRSTCASE=1   /IMPORTCASE=ALL   /VARIABLES= 
> >     V1 5X   Date ADATE10   !SYMB + 'O' F7.2
> >
> > Error # 1.  Command name: +
> >     The first word in the line is not recognized as an SPSS Statistics command.
> >     Execution of this command stops.   !SYMB + 'H' F7.2
> >
> > Error # 1.  Command name: +
> >     The first word in the line is not recognized as an SPSS Statistics command.
> >     Execution of this command stops.   !SYMB + 'L' F7.2
> >
> > Error # 1.  Command name: +
> >     The first word in the line is not recognized as an SPSS Statistics command.
> >     Execution of this command stops.   !SYMB + 'C' F7.2.
> >
> > Error # 1.  Command name: +
> >     The first word in the line is not recognized as an SPSS Statistics command.
> >     Execution of this command stops. CACHE. EXECUTE.
> >
> > Error # 105.  Command name: EXECUTE
> >     This command is not valid before a working file has been defined.
> >     Execution of this command stops. DATASET NAME "DataSet" + !SYMB WINDOW=FRONT.

How should I be doing this?

**Output on suggested macro**:

```
/* settings */
define !SYMB() "VIX" !enddefine.
define !CSVFILE() !quo(!con("E:\Downloads\$", !unq(!eva(!SYMB)), ".csv")) !enddefine.
define !c(str1 = !tok(1) /str2 = !tok(1)) !con(!unq(str1), !unq(str2)) !end.
define !cq(str1 = !tok(1) /str2 = !tok(1)) !quo(!con(!unq(str1), !unq(str2))) !end.

/* import csv file */
GET DATA
  /TYPE=TXT
  /FILE=!CSVFILE /DELCASE=LINE
  /DELIMITERS=","
  /ARRANGEMENT=DELIMITED
  /FIRSTCASE=1
  /IMPORTCASE=ALL
  /VARIABLES=
  V1 5X
  Date ADATE10
  !c !str1=!SYMB str2="O" F7.2

>Warning # 210 in column 2.  Text: !str1
>A macro symbol is invalid in this context.
>The symbol will be treated as an invalid special character.
  !c !str1=!SYMB str2="H" F7.2

>Warning # 210 in column 2.  Text: !str1
>A macro symbol is invalid in this context.
>The symbol will be treated as an invalid special character.
  !c !str1=!SYMB str2="L" F7.2

>Warning # 210 in column 2.  Text: !str1
>A macro symbol is invalid in this context.
>The symbol will be treated as an invalid special character.
  !c !str1=!SYMB str2="C" F7.2.

>Warning # 210 in column 2.  Text: !str1
>A macro symbol is invalid in this context.
>The symbol will be treated as an invalid special character.

>Error.  Command name: GET DATA
>(2265) Unrecognized or invalid variable format.  The format is invalid.  For
>numeric formats, the width or decimals value may be invalid.
>Execution of this command stops.
CACHE.
EXECUTE.

>Error # 105.  Command name: EXECUTE
>This command is not valid before a working file has been defined.
>Execution of this command stops.
DATASET NAME !cq !str1="DataSet" !str2=!SYMB WINDOW=FRONT.
```

**Test output:**

```
set err=off.
set mpr=on.
set printback=on.
  11  0 M>  set printback=on.

  12  0 M>  
!c str1="A" str2="B".
  13  0 M>  !c str1="A" str2="B".
!cq str1="A" str2="B".
  14  0 M>  !cq str1="A" str2="B".

  15  0 M>  
set printback=off.
  16  0 M>  set printback=off.
```

Comment: You have to define !c() and !cq() before running the test.

Answer (score 2):

SPSS macro language is tricky.

1) You have to do concatenation of strings inside macro;

2) Avoid dots in macro commands - if they are not necessary;

3) Do not end the line with macro command.

Try this untested syntax:

```
/* settings */
define !SYMB() "VIX" !enddefine.
define !CSVFILE() !quo(!con("E:\Downloads\$", !unq(!eva(!SYMB)), ".csv")) !enddefine.
define !c(str1 = !tok(1) /str2 = !tok(1)) !con(!unq(!str1), !unq(!str2)) !end.
define !cq(str1 = !tok(1) /str2 = !tok(1)) !quo(!con(!unq(!str1), !unq(!str2))) !end.

/* import csv file */
GET DATA
  /TYPE=TXT
  /FILE=!CSVFILE /DELCASE=LINE
  /DELIMITERS=","
  /ARRANGEMENT=DELIMITED
  /FIRSTCASE=1
  /IMPORTCASE=ALL
  /VARIABLES=
    V1 5X
    Date ADATE10
    !c str1=!SYMB str2="O" F7.2
    !c str1=!SYMB str2="H" F7.2
    !c str1=!SYMB str2="L" F7.2
    !c str1=!SYMB str2="C" F7.2.

EXECUTE.

DATASET NAME !cq str1="DataSet" str2=!SYMB WINDOW=FRONT.
```

Could you please run this test syntax and post the result you get in the Output.

```
set err=off.
set mpr=on.
set printback=on.

!c str1="A" str2="B".
!cq str1="A" str2="B".

set printback=off.
set mpr=off.
set err=on.
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not seem to run. What is !quo, !unq and !eva? When I run the code I get the output I have added to my original post.

Comment: These are short names for macro functions !quote(), !unquote() and !eval(). I did some error correction. Try to run the code now. Unfortunately I do not have SPSS with me now. I can not test the code.

Comment: That almost works. What is the difference between !c and !cq? I am getting this error: ```Warnings Expecting dataset name or WINDOW. Found DataSetVIX. Execution of this command stops.```

Comment: !c() is for combining strings with unquoted result. !cq() is the same, but the result should be quoted. See my edited answer.

Comment: Seems it works for me:
!c str1=A str2=B.
  88  0 M>  AB
!cq str1=A str2=B.
  90  0 M>  'AB'

Comment: I added the output to my original post. The problem is not with the cq function I think, its with the DATASET NAME command. It does seem to work, as it imports the file. However, the new window does not have the correct dataset name.

Comment: Fixed by changing the last line to ```DATASET NAME !c str1="DataSet" str2=!SYMB WINDOW=FRONT.```

Answer (score 0):

Macros are indeed tricky.  For your purposes, I suggest that you use the simpler FILE HANDLE command to define your inputs.  You can read about it in the Syntax Reference manual accessible from the Help menu.

HTH,
Jon Peck

Comment: FILE HANDLE will not handle variable names in GET DATA.

Comment: FILE HANDLE is for abstracting the file name/location.